# Do you have to pay immigration to leave Malaysia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, fees-and-charges, malaysia

I have a friend who says she needs to pay immigration and also pay to exit the country. Is this true?

Comment: Malaysia, like most countries, charges an exit tax; however, this amount is charged at the time of booking. [There is no separate airport tax](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/MY-Malaysia-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) paid at departure.

Comment: What is the country of residence? of passport? does the friend have a valid visa or has it expired?

Comment: @pnuts "An introduction to love or dating scams"?!  Are you sure that's the right link?

Answer (score 2):

You only have to do this if you have overstayed your visa and there are penalties levied.

Otherwise there is not such tax on departure.

Comment: Can you provide a source to back this up? It's useful to provide the OP with evidence.

Comment: Personal experience. I will hunt for some official link. This happened to a sibling who overstayed and then had to pay the penalty before being allowed to clear immigration and board the flight.

Comment: Fair enough, it's just worth stating your source in the answer - if it's personal experience, say so, and explain what happened to the sibling.  Gives people confidence in your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pay anything unless if you overstayed. Depending on how long you overstated,  they will let you know how much. We said we didn't have money then they told us we should pay on our next visit. We did our return but they never charged us.